# MS Word VBA for formfields

Tags: vba, ms-word, form-fields

I am trying to assign a numeric value in VBA for a dropdown formfield. I have the Msgbox just to test functionality:

```
Sub ScreenB()
    Dim a As Double
    If ActiveDocument.FormFields("Dropdown9").DropDown.Value = No Then
        a = 1
    Else
        a = 2
    End If
    MsgBox a       
End Sub
```

With this code, my Msgbox does not change (it reads "2"), even when I change the the dropdown from Yes to No, or vice-versa.  I also tried putting quotes around yes ("Yes") in the VBA code and got a Type Mismatch error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [FormFields.Result](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837885.aspx)

```
Sub ScreenB()
    Dim a As Double
    If ActiveDocument.FormFields("Dropdown9").Result = "No" Then
        a = 1
    Else
        a = 2
    End If
    MsgBox a       
End Sub
```